# AWK script to launch a process as loop for several txt files

Tags: text-processing, awk, scripting

I have plenty of files. I need a script that iterates each file and prints columns 2 and 3 and G as first column in another file. The input files are named as `UH001 UH002, UH003,...,UH123` and the output named as `HU001,HU002,HU0013,...,HU123`.

input

```
H01 offset
H02 time
H03 penetration
1 2 3
4 5 6
4 5 6
7 9 1
```

output

```
G 2 3
G 5 6
G 5 6
G 9 1
```

Comment: You need full-stops. This is un-readable.

Comment: We don't generally act as a script-writing service. What have you tried so far? If it didn't do what you want, how have you tried to fix it?

Comment: Is it just a case of replacing first numeric fields with `G` and ignoring all other lines?

Comment: What about the `H0[1-3]` lines?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this might be all you need (untested):

```
awk '
    FNR==1 { close(out); out=FILENAME; sub(/UH/,"HU",out) }
    FNR>3  { $1="G"; print > out }
' UH*
```